Generalization of "Fermat–Apollonius circle"
In geometry, the director circle of an ellipse (also called the orthoptic circle or Fermat–Apollonius circle) is a circle consisting of all points where two perpendicular tangent lines to the ellipse cross each other.
If the ellipse is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, then the Fermat–Apollonius circle is $x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2$.

Generalization:
Given an ellipse $ E: \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $, two tangents to the ellipse $ E $ pass through the point $ P(m, n) $, with the points of tangency being $ A $ and $ B $. The angle $ \langle \overrightarrow{PA}, \overrightarrow{PB} \rangle $ between the vectors $ \overrightarrow{PA} $ and $ \overrightarrow{PB} $ is a constant $ \theta( 0 < \theta < \pi )$.

The question is:
Find the equation of the locus of the point $ P $.

My attempt:
It is well known that the equation of the tangent lines to the ellipse passing through $ P(m, n) $ is
$$
(m^2 - a^2)k^2 - 2mnk + (n^2 - b^2) = 0,
$$
where $ k $ is the slope of the tangent lines (if the slope exists). Let the slopes of the two tangent lines be $ k_1 $ and $ k_2 $, then
$$
k_1 + k_2 = \frac{2mn}{m^2 - a^2}, \quad k_1k_2 = \frac{n^2 - b^2}{m^2 - a^2}.
$$
When $ \theta $ is an acute angle, we have
$$
\tan \theta = \left| \frac{k_1 - k_2}{1 + k_1k_2} \right| = \sqrt{\frac{(k_1 + k_2)^2 - 4k_1k_2}{(1 + k_1k_2)^2}}=2\sqrt{\frac{a^2n^2+b^2m^2-a^2b^2}{(m^2-a^2)(m^2+n^2-a^2-b^2)}}.
$$
Similarly, when $ \theta $ is an obtuse angle, we have
$$
\tan \theta = -\left| \frac{k_1 - k_2}{1 + k_1k_2} \right| = -\sqrt{\frac{(k_1 + k_2)^2 - 4k_1k_2}{(1 + k_1k_2)^2}}=-2\sqrt{\frac{a^2n^2+b^2m^2-a^2b^2}{(m^2-a^2)(m^2+n^2-a^2-b^2)}}.
$$
I would like to know if there is a simpler expression for the equation of the locus of $ P(m, n) $.

You didn't square the $(1+k_1k_2)$ in the denominator of the radical expression. Doing so gives something we can write as
$$\tan\theta = \pm2\frac{\sqrt{b^2m^2+a^2n^2-a^2b^2}}{|m^2+n^2-a^2-b^2|}$$ Note that we can drop the $\pm$ and the absolute value, since the signs of $\tan\theta$ and $m^2+n^2-a^2-b^2$ must match: for acute $\theta$, we have $\tan\theta>0$, while point $P$ lies outside the director circle so that $m^2+n^2>a^2+b^2$; similarly, obtuse $\theta$ switches each $>$ to $<$. (And, of course, the square root itself is taken to be non-negative.)
I'd prefer to write the resulting equation as
$$m^2+n^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\cot\theta\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2}-1}$$ so that the case $\theta=90^\circ$ simply makes the final term vanish instead of introducing an off-putting infinity. Pulling $ab$ out of the radical is a bit of a stylistic choice; I like the echo of the original ellipse relation inside the radical, and I like that the term is the product of $ab$ and a dimensionless value.

This equation is beautiful and concise!

If you write $$k_1,k_2 = \tan \theta_, \tan \theta_2$$ you have the tangent addition formula (for small angles)
$$\tan \theta = \tan (\theta_1  -   \theta_2 ) = \frac{\tan \theta_1 - \tan \theta_2 } {1+\tan \theta_1 \ \tan  \theta_2 } $$
or the inverse
$$z = \tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1} y = \tan^{-1}\frac{x+ y}{1-  x y}$$
In all of $\mathbb R^2$ the formula is valid for $| x y |<1$, otherwise switch to $\tan^{-1}\frac{x+ y}{1-  x y } \pm\pi $ for $x+y </> 0 $
